# Extjs - Toolbar is correct but grid is wrong

Tags: extjs, grid, toolbar

i have a grid with a toolbar. The Toolbar is ok (i have 15 entries so 3 pages with 5 entries), but the grid shows all 15 entries and not just 5.

I can't figure out, what the Problem is.

So hier is my Code: 
(the aFile is an array that i have to put together local)
it looks like:

```
var aFile = [{'time':'time text', 'info':'infotext'},{'time':'time2 text', 'info':'infotext2'}]
```

and the Rest of the Code:

```
    var PageNumber = 5;

    var oStore = new Ext.data.Store({
       pageSize: PageNumber,
       autoLoad:false,
       storeId:'store1',
       fields:['time', 'info'],
       data: aFile
    });

    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
       store       : oStore,
       pageSize    : PageNumber,
       lid         : 'file'+id,
       columns     : [
           { id : 'time', header:'Time', sortable: false, dataIndex: 'time', flex:1},
           { id : 'info', header:'Info', sortable: false, dataIndex: 'info', flex:5}
       ],
       title       : name,
       bbar        : new Ext.PagingToolbar({
           store       : oStore,
           dock        :'bottom',
           displayInfo :true,
           pageSize    : PageNumber
       })
   });
   oStore.load({
       params:{
           start:0,
           limit: PageNumber
       }});
   grid.reconfigure();
   oPanelCenter.add(grid);
```

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs, paging is relying on the server side to support paging. If you use a local file, you must configure a MemoryProxy with enablePaging.